# Responsive text width in LI with icon image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass

I have a list of products that I want to display with a thumb icon
on the left of each item.

How can I have the product description display on the right without wrapping
the text on smaller screens.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="cf">
      <span id="customizeImage1" class="product-customize-image"></span>
      <div class="product-menu-txt">
        <a href="/Product/Customize/769497">Friend Maker - Serves 8-10</a>
        ($14.99)<br>
        6 Donuts<br>
        6 Bagel &amp; Cream Cheese - 1 (8oz) tub<br>
        An assortment of our most favored varieties.
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: Tahoma,Sans-Serif;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.product-customize-image {
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:red;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.product-menu-txt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/girum/4/edit

[image: wrapped text on smaller screen]

[image: Text that fits the width of the row]

Comment: use media queries, align text right side

Comment: best way to handle this is to use media-queries so that all the devices render appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to use `table` layout with image and text displayed as `table-cell`s.

*Relevant CSS*:

```
li {
  display: table;
}

.product-customize-image {
  display:table-cell;
}

.product-menu-txt {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

*Demo*: http://jsbin.com/banuvoharo/1/

Comment: these seems to solve my text issue but now if I use an image sprite the second sprite below displays

Comment: Fix the size of the span.

Comment: looks like the height of the span is controlled by the height of the biggest table-cell in the table which would be the text. I still think this answer is correct just might need to put padding on the sprite or wrap the image in a container that is then display:table-cell

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. Will need to wrap that. Will try and work out in next 10-15 mins.

Comment: @BillPull: Here. You could wrap the image span inside of a div with fixed-width and height to match your sprite size. Demo: http://jsbin.com/lifegoladu/2/